# lightning email template is not showing the merge value of opportunity fields

Tags: email, visual-workflow, email-template

Lightning email template is not showing the merge value of the opportunity fields
I have created the lightning email template for sending email, the template Id I'm trying to use in my flow to trigger the email based on the use case, but when I try to see the email, values of the merge fields in opportunity related entity type are coming blank. Please anyone can tell me why it's happening, I have mapped in related record in opportunity as well and enhanced email is enabled. If anyone could help in giving appoach to solve this issue

Comment: Check read permissions on objects and fields. Also check record sharing.

Comment: yeah that is already given on object n fields as profile is system admin

Comment: Even a System Admin needs explicitly the permission to read a field. Make sure you have that.

Comment: Yeah I have checked there is the permision for object abd field for read access